# $http request with a $scope value included in url

Tags: angularjs

say i am making a $http request

```
    $http.get('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=Manchester&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=1e9bfc54489901fe117e6f2877018')
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.worldweather = response;
});
```

but i want to replace the city name in the url with a scope value, i figured id be able to do it like this but alas no. Any suggestions?

```
$scope.city = 'Manchester';


    $http.get('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=' + city + '&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=1e9bfc54489901fe117e6f2877018')
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.worldweather = response;
});
```

Comment: Why `city` and not `$scope.city` as the variable?

Comment: Actually there was a reason because i wanted too attach and input to the scope city i.e... <input ng-model="city"> to search .. this isn't working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`city` is a variable in the current context. `$scope.city` is a property on the `$scope` object. They are not the same thing. Try:

```
    $http.get('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=' + $scope.city + '&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=1e9bfc54489901fe117e6f2877018')
```

But in general, it may be easier to use params to `$http` for the query string rather than building it manually

```
 $http.get('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx',{
   params: {
    q:$scope.city,
    format:json,
    num_of_days:5,
    key: 1e9bfc54489901fe117e6f2877018
   })
```